# How to stop storyboard animation in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've made an animation with storyboard in Blend. The animation is in the MainPage and is very simple.

1) When my app starts, an image from the bottom of the screen moves at the top of the screen.

2) I also have a button at the MainPage. When i press it, it goes from the MainPage to the SecondPage.

When i'm on the SecondPage and i press the back button(the hard key on my cellphone) it goes to MainPage and the animation starts again. How can i stop this? I want the animation to play only when i start the application from scratch. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your project find App.xaml.cs and edit the code inside this function

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Add a boolean variable here say showanimation. And set it true.

On Mainpage, in the code behind, override OnNavigatedTo function and check for boolean value, if true then start animation else do nothing. Also dont forget to set the variable to false after starting animation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think i'm doing something wrong. I add the boolean variable but what do you mean when you say "check for boolean value". Can you be more specific. Thanks :)

Comment: create a `static` boolean variable in the App.xaml.cs. And set it to true inside this function. In mainPage.xaml.cs, check `App.showanimation == true`? if yes then show animation else not.

Comment: here's the code:

    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            static bool showanimation = true;
        }


But i have an error: "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item"

Comment: This is incorrect. Static variable should be declared outside the function inside the App class and set it true inside the function. So that it could be referred in MainPage via `App.ShowAnimation`. I hope it helps.